# How to improve indentation for complicated Typescript function declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have the following method definition in some typescript code:

```js
  modifyPose({description, shot, timelineId, timeline, paramStorePath, mutator}:
  {description: string;
   shot: SceneShot;
   timelineId: 'scene'|'camera';
   timeline: PoseTimeline;
   paramStorePath: string[];
   mutator: (timeline: PoseTimeline) => void}) {
    this.poseMutation({timeline, mutator})
    this.requestSave({shot, path: paramStorePath})
  }
```

It's a method that takes a destructured payload with particular types, including a function.
The problem is it's virtually unreadable. Who can see at a glance that the function body begins with the open-brace on line 7? It's not even obvious that most of the lines before line 7 are arg type declarations.

I can of course declare an interface for this and move it out of the way, and that cleans it up. But it's a method, so the interface would have to be way up at the top of the class, which isn't so nice. For times like this when inline is better for whatever reason, it seems like this indentation would be far superior:

```js
  modifyPose({description, shot, timelineId, timeline, paramStorePath, mutator}:
             {description: string;
              shot: SceneShot;
              timelineId: 'scene'|'camera';
              timeline: PoseTimeline;
              paramStorePath: string[];
              mutator: (timeline: PoseTimeline) => void
             }) {
    this.poseMutation({timeline, mutator})
    this.requestSave({shot, path: paramStorePath})
  }
```

but eslint won't let me get away with that; it "fixes" it to the former version.
Aside from just whining about it, is there any way to convince eslint that my way is more readable?

Comment: `type`s and `interface`s don't have to be declared before use. You can put them at the bottom, or extract them to another module. Personally I'd say that, even in pure JavaScript, you are reaching a readability limit in terms of the number of destructured arguments once you have that many.

Comment: Did you consider declaring a type for an object that the method expects as an argument?

Comment: @Shlang: yes, see this in my post: "I can of course declare an interface for this and move it out of the way, and that cleans it up." -- and also see why that's not the solution I'm hoping for.